# Time related function for calculate rate like reddit

Tags: ranking, reddit

As we know that reddit has its ranking algorithm as well as stackoverflow.

[image: reddit ranking algorithm]

I want to development a ranking algorithm for audit content dynamic ranking. Users can audit the contents by digg/bury. The ranking algorithm is for making the oldest/fewest actions content be auditted first.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the classical formulas: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/reddit-stumbleupon-delicious-and-hacker-news-algorithms-exposed

> **Formula:**
>
> `(p - 1) / (t + 2)^1.5`
>
> **Description:**
>
> Votes divided by age factor
>
> p = votes (points) from users.
>   t = time since submission in hours.
>
> p is subtracted by 1 to negate submitters vote.
>   age factor is (time since submission in hours plus two) to the power of 1.5.